# Iterating over pandas dataframe with several conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

So I have this data frame which contains the positions of different point, X, Y, Z and several other properties. Then, I have another disctionary called path() which contains different points that form a trajectory. These points are included in the data frame.

For graphing reasons, I want to set the column "path" to equal to 2 ONLY for the points that are in the path(). How can I identify which points of the dataframe are in this path and change their "path" attribute?

Clarification:

Path is something like this:

```
path = {12, 34, 14}
```

and pos{} gives the [x,y,z] for each node of the path

```
pos = {12: [3, 4, 2], 34: [1, 3, 4], 14: [5, 4, 5]}
```

where [3, 4, 2] = [x, y, z] like the ones in the data frame. So what I want to do is to change the column "path" in the dataframe from 1 to 2 for the positions in the dataframe that match this one. So, for example, if for 14: [5, 4, 55] there is a row in the dataframe with X = 5, Y = 4 and Z = 55 I want this row to have path = 2.

This is what I tried and what I think that it should work but it doesn't. Basicallt I try to filter for position and then modify the dataframe correspondingly.

(here I'm trying to change from 0 to 1 instead of 1 to 2 because the image of the df I gave you is one I modified while trying this but ignore it)

```
df['path'] = np.zeros(len(df.index))

filt1 = (df['eventID'] == 98)
df_path = df[filt1]

for node in path:

     A, B, C = pos[node]
     filt2 = (df['X'] == A) & (df['Y'] == B) & (df['Z'] == C)

     df_path[filt2]['path'].replace({0:1})
```

Also, I get this warning:

```
UserWarning:

Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
```

Sorry if I'm "violating" some frowned upon rules, I'm new here.
Thank you very much

Àlex

Comment: Hi Alex, please provide a [mcve] of your dataframe in text, not image. and provide your sample output along with your attempt if any.

Comment: This seems far too broad/vague, and likely off-topic. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

```
df['path'] = np.zeros(len(df.index))

filt1 = (df['eventID'] == 98)
df_path = df[filt1]

for node in path:

   A, B, C = pos[node]
   filt2 = (df['X'] == A) & (df['Y'] == B) & (df['Z'] == C)

   df_path['path'].loc[filt2] = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

**1. find the key [using this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) you want from the dictionary**

```
>>> dishes = {'eggs': 2, 'sausage': 1, 'bacon': 1, 'spam': 500}
>>> keys = dishes.keys()
>>> # keys and values are iterated over in the same order (insertion order)
>>> list(keys)
['eggs', 'sausage', 'bacon', 'spam']
```

**2. Now to change replace the path attribute**
[using this](https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-replace-column-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": ["a", "b", "a"]})
print(df)
OUTPUT
  column1
0       a
1       b
2       a

df["column1"].replace({"a": "x", "b": "y"}, inplace=True)
print(df)
OUTPUT
  column1
0       x
1       y
2       x
```